# python error:ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

Tags: python, selenium

I write a python program in pycharm,including FBCrawl.py,html_login.py,common/glovar.py,in glovar.py, I define a variable webdriver_browser, and want use this webdriver_browser in FBCrawl.py AND html_login.py,the main purpose is to log in facebook and get content of a page,using selenium,the program are as follows, but when running it, 
**it errors:**

```
C:\Python\Python36\python.exe           C:/Python/PyCharmProject/FaceBookCrawl/FBCrawl.py
None
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x00000146BF1FD438>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 173, in __del__
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 149, in stop
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 120, in send_remote_shutdown_command
 ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

 Process finished with exit code 0
```

**The program are here:**

FBCrwal.py:

```
from common import glovar
from html_login import HtmlLogin
from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == '__main__':

    baseurl = "http://www.google.com"
    #log in the website
    login_url = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110"
    HtmlLogin().login(login_url)
    html_cont = glovar.webdriver_browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/alexis.n.griffith.3")
    print(html_cont)
```

html_login.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from common import glovar


class HtmlLogin(object):

    def login(self,url):
        if url is None:
            return
        login_url = url
        glovar.webdriver_browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        glovar.webdriver_browser.get(login_url)
        #user credentials
        user =  glovar.webdriver_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#email")
        user.send_keys('********@gmail.com')
        password = glovar.webdriver_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#pass")
        password.send_keys('********')
        login = glovar.webdriver_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#loginbutton")
        login.click()
```

glovar.py:

```
webdriver_browser =  None
```

could you please tell me the reason and how to solve it

Comment: and why execute "print(html_cont)",the output is "None"

Answer (score 2):

The error can arise if you have multithreading being used to run background tasks and the main program thread finishes. At that point the Python interpreter will start to be destroyed, but if a background task in a daemon thread is still running and is running in C code it can still get to run.

This causes problems because the interpreter is part way through being destroyed. A symptom of this occurring is what you see and is because when destroying the interpreter, any object lookups in modules start to return `None` as the contents of the module have been cleared. This is being detected and you get that error.

How to solve it this case really depends on what the code is doing. One way might be to identify the background task and wait for it to finish, possibly using some way to signal that the thread should stop if it otherwise would run indefinitely.

An alternate cause which in digging into the selenium code is perhaps a better explanation is where `__del__`() methods are added to objects to do work and these are being called when objects are being destroyed on interpreter shutdown. If you trace through the selenium code they are from within a `__del__()` method doing a lazy import of a module. Because `__del__()` is being called when the interpreter is being destroyed, the module has already been cleared as explain about and it fails.

The only thing you maybe able to do if this is the case, is explicitly stop the selenium driver yourself from within your code before exiting the program. That way you have done it before the interpreter gets destroyed.

This is a question you should really ask the selenium folks, or look at the documentation to see if you are using the API wrongly. That said, it is bad practice to do stuff in `__del__`() method like the selenium code is doing. So long as they keep doing it this way, it might be hard to stop it unless you are just using their API wrong.

Comment: but in this program,I have not use multithread, could you please modify the program directly

Answer (score 2):

if you're still looking for the answer: try ending your script using

```
glovar.webdriver_browser.quit()
```

I had the same error and it has been resolved just by adding this line. Hope it helped